# Microsoft.Web.Helpers not visible in the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, installation, package

When I install package Microsoft.Web.Helpers I get next warning txt file (after installing):
**If the package is installed in an ASP.NET MVC 3 site, the site will not work.
If you’ve already installed the package into an MVC 3 application, uninstall it.
If the MVC 3 site does not work even after you have uninstalled the package, you might need to reinstall the ASP.NET MVC 3 packages as well.**
I can use Microsoft.Web.Helpers in controller class but cant in the view (@using Microsoft.Web.Helpers not found).
I trying do next: [Using ReCaptcha with MVC3 and razor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666438/using-recaptcha-with-mvc3-and-razor)       [ReCaptcha and MVC3, problems getting Microsoft.Web.Helpers working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276354/recaptcha-and-mvc3-problems-getting-microsoft-web-helpers-working) .But it doesnt help.What I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the namespace in Views\Web.config (not the app root web.config).

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Comment: by the irony of the case I had to reverse in the root register namespace.Thanks for idea,Rick.But then I have next eror while debug:Conflicting versions of ASP.NET Web Pages detected: specified version is "1.0.0.0", but the version in bin is "2.0.0.0". To continue, remove files from the application's bin directory or remove the version specification in web.config. -> I do both but still have problems.

Comment: also I doing this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215045/conflicting-versions-error-adding-asp-net-mvc-3-web-role-to-windows-azure-projec